# Riverpod with Hooks doesn't rebuild ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, riverpod

I've implemented a simple ListView using [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod). There's a button that adds a new item(`Other Store`) to the ListView, but when I click it the ListView doesn't change. I know the item is being added to the list because I checked the value of `storeList` by printing it. Any ideas why the `ListView.separated` doesn't rebuild when the list changes?

Packages:
flutter_hooks: 0.17.0
hooks_riverpod: 0.14.0
state_notifier: 0.7.0

```dart
class StoreListController extends StateNotifier<List<String>> {
  StoreListController() : super(['First Store']);
  void add() => state.add('Other Store');
}
```

```dart
final storeListProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<StoreListController, List<String>>(
  (_) => StoreListController(),
);

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final storeList = useProvider(storeListProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ListView Sample'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(storeList[index]),
        ),
        itemCount: storeList.length,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context.read(storeListProvider.notifier).add(),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is how you are modifying your state in your StateNotifier.

For the state to update, you have to actually replace the state object.

Change your add function to the following:

```dart
void add() => state = [...state, 'Other Store'];
```

[Here's an example](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/tree/master/examples/todos) from the developer of Riverpod that demonstrates array modifications as the state of a StateNotifier.